# Why quote> prompt opens when running script with the button

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I created a new folder and a new conda environment and opened it in VSCode. However, when I try to run any Python script with the Run button I get the `quote>` prompt waiting for the input. What's wrong with my set-up?

> user@c1 my-project % /Users/user/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python
> /Users/user/Desktop/my-project/src/script.py quote>

That refers to any python script, even the simplest one like below calls this behaviour:

```
print(2+2)
```

This is my OUTPUT panel with Python selected:

```
User belongs to experiment group 'pythonaa'
User belongs to experiment group 'pythonSendEntireLineToREPL'
User belongs to experiment group 'pythonNotDisplayLinterPrompt'
User belongs to experiment group 'ShowPlayIcon - start'
User belongs to experiment group 'ShowExtensionSurveyPrompt - control'
User belongs to experiment group 'DebugAdapterFactory - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'PtvsdWheels37 - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'UseTerminalToGetActivatedEnvVars - control'
User belongs to experiment group 'LocalZMQKernel - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'CollectLSRequestTiming - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'CollectNodeLSRequestTiming - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'EnableIPyWidgets - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'DeprecatePythonPath - control'
User belongs to experiment group 'RunByLine - experiment'
User belongs to experiment group 'CustomEditorSupport - control'
> conda --version
> pyenv root
> python3.7 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python3 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python3.6 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python2 ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> ~/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
> conda info --json
> conda info --json
> conda info --json
> conda info --json
> conda env list
> conda info --json
Python interpreter path: ~/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python
Starting Jedi Python language engine.
> conda info --json
> conda env list
> ~/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.prefix)"
cwd: ~/Desktop/my-project
> ~/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.prefix)"
cwd: ~/Desktop/my-project
> ~/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
cwd: ~/Desktop/my-project
> ~/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "import sys;print(sys.executable)"
cwd: ~/Desktop/my-project
> ~/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"
cwd: ~/Desktop/my-project
> ~/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py -c "from distutils.sysconfig import get_python_lib; print(get_python_lib())"
cwd: ~/Desktop/my-project
> ~/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py site --user-site
cwd: ~/Desktop/my-project
> ~/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py site --user-site
cwd: ~/Desktop/my-project
> ~/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/completion.py
> ~/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/completion.py
Error 2021-02-28 11:15:20: stderr jediProxy Error (stderr) /Users/user/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/completion.py:584: DeprecationWarning: Deprecated since version 0.16.0. Use Script(...).get_names instead.
  jedi.api.names(

> ~/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py pylint --disable=all --enable=F,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,unused-wildcard-import,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode,E0001,E0011,E0012,E0100,E0101,E0102,E0103,E0104,E0105,E0107,E0108,E0110,E0111,E0112,E0113,E0114,E0115,E0116,E0117,E0118,E0202,E0203,E0211,E0213,E0236,E0237,E0238,E0239,E0240,E0241,E0301,E0302,E0303,E0401,E0402,E0601,E0602,E0603,E0604,E0611,E0632,E0633,E0701,E0702,E0703,E0704,E0710,E0711,E0712,E1003,E1101,E1102,E1111,E1120,E1121,E1123,E1124,E1125,E1126,E1127,E1128,E1129,E1130,E1131,E1132,E1133,E1134,E1135,E1136,E1137,E1138,E1139,E1200,E1201,E1205,E1206,E1300,E1301,E1302,E1303,E1304,E1305,E1306,E1310,E1700,E1701 --msg-template='{line},{column},{category},{symbol}:{msg}' --reports=n --output-format=text ~/Desktop/my-project/src/script.py
cwd: ~/Desktop/my-project
> ~/miniconda3/envs/my-env/bin/python ~/.vscode/extensions/ms-python.python-2021.2.582707922/pythonFiles/pyvsc-run-isolated.py pylint --disable=all --enable=F,unreachable,duplicate-key,unnecessary-semicolon,global-variable-not-assigned,unused-variable,unused-wildcard-import,binary-op-exception,bad-format-string,anomalous-backslash-in-string,bad-open-mode,E0001,E0011,E0012,E0100,E0101,E0102,E0103,E0104,E0105,E0107,E0108,E0110,E0111,E0112,E0113,E0114,E0115,E0116,E0117,E0118,E0202,E0203,E0211,E0213,E0236,E0237,E0238,E0239,E0240,E0241,E0301,E0302,E0303,E0401,E0402,E0601,E0602,E0603,E0604,E0611,E0632,E0633,E0701,E0702,E0703,E0704,E0710,E0711,E0712,E1003,E1101,E1102,E1111,E1120,E1121,E1123,E1124,E1125,E1126,E1127,E1128,E1129,E1130,E1131,E1132,E1133,E1134,E1135,E1136,E1137,E1138,E1139,E1200,E1201,E1205,E1206,E1300,E1301,E1302,E1303,E1304,E1305,E1306,E1310,E1700,E1701 --msg-template='{line},{column},{category},{symbol}:{msg}' --reports=n --output-format=text ~/Desktop/my-project/src/script.py
cwd: ~/Desktop/my-project
##########Linting Output - pylint##########

--------------------------------------------------------------------
Your code has been rated at 10.00/10 (previous run: 10.00/10, +0.00)
```

Comment: could you post some code?

Comment: Please check out the edit.

Comment: Looks like VSCode configure relative. Could you provide the some information of the plugins from _OUTPUT_ panel?

Comment: @rustyhu, Please see the edit. Did you ask about this or soemthing else?

Comment: @jakes If you are using latest version VScode advise you to install `Pylance` extension and use it as the default python language server, instead of `Jedi`, then attemp to run the script.

Comment: @jakes -In VS Code, its internal terminal integrates the terminal from the system, so please make sure that the terminal of the system can run python code. (Enter "python" in the system terminal and then enter the code.)

Comment: @jakes -In addition, it is recommended that you use a new VS Code terminal (Ctrl+Shift+`) and make sure that the executed file has been saved.

Answer (score 0):

In the bottom left corner, do you see the python version? If yes click on it and then select the virtual env. Alternatively, you can press Cntrl + p and then search for `python interpreter` then select the environment.

[image]
[image]

Comment: The bottom left corner already shows the correct env.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I finally decided to create a new project folder, copy the content and the script ran fine. Trying to investigate the issue I noticed that the source of the problem was really silly - my true project folder name contained `'` (single quote) sign. And the second one I created didn't. I changed the name of the second folder to include the single quote and the issue came back, this time showing `>` sign only as a prompt. So it seems there was nothing wrong with VSCode settings, nor with conda env. I'll leave my finding here as an answer in case someone else encounters this issue.